# ListView continuously recreating upon Activity changes.

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, android-activity

I have this `ListView`; but the `ListView` keeps recreating itself when I leave and or return to the `Activity`. What is causing this and what should I be looking for in the following code

```
public class Homepage extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);
        ImageView i = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Ion.with(i).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .load("http://192.168.1.6/webservice/images/image1.jpg");

        // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download json data
        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
        // Starting the download process
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);

        // Getting a reference to ListView of activity_main
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myList);
        startService(new Intent(this, NotificationService.class));

    }
    ....

    String strUrl = "http://192.168.1.6/webservice/events.php";
    ListView mListView;

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                    .openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
        String data = null;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
            try {
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread
            ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();

            // Start parsing xml data
            listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter> {

        JSONObject jObject;

        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                JSONParser newJsonParser = new JSONParser();
                newJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            JSONParser newJsonParser = new JSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed events list
            List<HashMap<String, Object>> posts = null;

            try {
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                posts = newJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
            }

            // Keys used in Hashmap
            String[] from = { "mytitle", "event_img", "mymessage", "mysponser",
                    "myevent_location", "myevent_whoinvited",
                    "myevent_dresscode", "myevent_time", "myevent_endtime" };

            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.title, R.id.event_pic, R.id.subTitle_single,
                    R.id.sponser, R.id.l, R.id.who, R.id.d, R.id.t, R.id.e };

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), posts,
                    R.layout.single_line, from, to);
            return adapter;
        }

        ....
        /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // Setting adapter for the listview
            mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
            // //Attempting Onclick method \\\\
            mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                ....
            });

            // //\\\\looks like this cycles through the image to the adapter
            // using the ImageLoaderTask
            for (int i = 0; i < adapter.getCount(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                        .getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("event_img_path");
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hm.put("event_img_path", imgUrl);
                hm.put("position", i);

                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in
                // the listview
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hm);
            }
        }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends
            AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>> {

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(
                HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {

            InputStream iStream = null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("event_img_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");

            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                        .openConnection();

                // Connecting to url
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                // Getting Caching directory
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"
                        + position + ".png");

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOutStream);

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                // Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position
                // in the listview
                HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();

                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("event_img", tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position", position);

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and
                // position
                return hmBitmap;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image
            String path = (String) result.get("event_img");

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview
            SimpleAdapter adapter = (SimpleAdapter) mListView.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the
            // listview
            // @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter
                    .getItem(position);

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter
            hm.put("event_img", path);

            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
```

I have already added `android:configChanges="orientation"`  to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: it should be android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" for device with API LEVEL > 11. Still it is not the correct way to manage it

Comment: That would only solve the orientation issue, if it works. but the listview will still recreate when activity comes back into focus. i was told it has something to do with the asynctask but that is beyond me.

Comment: because of onCreate() there you have the asytask and everytime it when the screen changes it will go in onCreate and it will call again the asyntask. Try blocking it with a boolean or there is a configuration when the screen changes onCreate will not be called if I recall it correctly.

Comment: i see a boolean. what if i put a boolean in the imageloadertask to check weither the image is already stored in cache?

Answer (score 0):

The `ListView` will always be destroyed as it is tied to your `Activity`'s lifecycle. Once the `Activity` dies, so does the `ListView`. To avoid this; set up some sort of data storage/retrieval that will store the `ArrayList` of info that you need and recreate it on `Activity` changes.

Also you added quite a bit of code; concise things down more to what you believe is causing the issues and related classes.

Create a new class file and put following code in:

```
    public class EagerSingleton {
    private ArrayList<MyClass> list = new ArrayList<MyClass>();;
    private static volatile EagerSingleton instance = null;

    // private constructor
    private EagerSingleton() {
    }

    public static EagerSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (EagerSingleton.class) {
                // Double check
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new EagerSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Then you can add getter and setter methods for the `ArrayList` parameter.

This means wherever you instantiate the Singleton somewhere you will have access to that arraylist.

Comment: i cut some code from my post. i believe the issue is that downloadtask(); is being run everytime the activity is created. but i am not sure, i am going to try to somehow make an if statement to check weither or not the data has already been downloaded...

Comment: so is your listview recreating; but is just empty? or is it populating data?

Comment: it is populating data fresh everytime, i want to have full control over when it refreshes.

Comment: Try storing that data in another class somewhere; perhaps a singleton object; and retrieving the data from the singleton object? That way it won't matter if it recreates the listview

Comment: wow sorry,keep in mind you are talking to a newbie here lol, im still in the learning process, can u break it down a little? what is singleton object?

Comment: in my edit; MyClass can be anything you want to store; it could be a POJO that contains variables you need to populate on your ListView or it could be primitive data types as well... whatever you feel like.

Comment: im still slightly confused, sorry. never seen this singleton thing before. im still reading up on it but cant i just set an if statement in the oncreate and say somethng like if downloadTask is already called, keep results?

Comment: Yea but how and where would you keep the results; you know what I am saying?

Comment: yea i know what you mean. at the moment i know the pictures are stored in a file in cache, i'm checking through the code to see where everything else is stored.